# Closing mobile nav toggle on click

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have a mobile nav menu with a hamburger toggle that successfully opens the menu on click. I am also adding animation to the toggle button on click. I am using a backdrop to close the nav menu, but I also want to be able to close the menu when the toggle is clicked, and if the backdrop is clicked, for the toggle to animate when the menu is closing. Below is my code so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var backdrop = document.querySelector(".backdrop");
var toggleButton = document.querySelector(".toggle-container");
var mobileNav = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav");

backdrop.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mobileNav.classList.remove("open");
  closeMenu();
});

function closeMenu() {

  if (toggleButton) {
    mobileNav.classList.remove("open");
  }
  backdrop.classList.remove("open");
  toggleButton.classList.remove("active");

}

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mobileNav.classList.add("open");
  toggleButton.classList.add("active");
  backdrop.classList.add("open");
});

function toggleNav(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 197px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.toggle-container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 105;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mobile-nav__items {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Quantico', sans-serif;
}

.mobile-nav__item {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.mobile-nav__item a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #15396c;
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
  .toggle-container {
    display: none;
  }
}

.open {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdrop"></div>

<div class="toggle-container" onclick="toggleNav(this)">
  <div class="bar1">
  </div>
  <div class="bar2">
  </div>
  <div class="bar3">
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="mobile-nav">
  <ul class="mobile-nav__items">
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Home
                        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Link 1
                        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Link 2
                        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Link 3
                        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Link 4
                        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome Mike! I have tried to run your code but it doesn't appear to be in working order. I've updated the question to turn it into a working example, but it seems we're missing some styles/elements/etc. Can you Edit the question to get it working so we can help?

Comment: Thanks Brett! I added some missing css.

Comment: Where is the backdrop element?

Comment: You can create a snippet to add the necessary HTML, CSS, and JS so we can see the result - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Sorry I thought I forgot something, I added the backdrop element to the HTML

Comment: I'm still seeing a list of links, instead of a toggle to open them. Perhaps some other classes are missing. For example, I see the CSS contains a `.change` class selector, but don't see that class used in the HTML.

Comment: The .change class selector is added via the JS in the toggleNav function as an onclick method. I will add more of my css asa well, I thought I did but I may not have saved

Comment: Great, thank you. For a question like this we should be able to run the code to see what the issue is, so if you can update it so the menu is up to date with your work in progress we'll be able to help quickly.

Comment: I may need to create this on codepen, my code is completely here as it is in my project but it's not working properly.

Comment: I noticed some syntax issues in the CSS, like missing closing brackets. I added that, and it's closer to working, but not quite. We may need to remove some of the CSS to create the minimum working example. It appears the menu is out of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned-up the JS and made some changes to get it working. Namely, I moved the inline `onClick` to the event listener, and merged a few of the other functions to make it easier to understand (but feel free to separate these if needed).

The major change was to add the `active` and `change` classes to the `toggleButton` when open, and then remove the `active` and `change` classes when the backdrop is clicked.

```js
var backdrop = document.querySelector(".backdrop");
var toggleButton = document.querySelector(".toggle-container");
var mobileNav = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav");

backdrop.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mobileNav.classList.remove("open");
  backdrop.classList.remove("open");
  toggleButton.classList.remove("active", "change");
});

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mobileNav.classList.add("open");
  toggleButton.classList.add("active", "change");
  backdrop.classList.add("open");
});
```

```css
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.toggle-container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 105;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mobile-nav__items {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Quantico', sans-serif;
}

.mobile-nav__item {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.mobile-nav__item a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #15396c;
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
  .toggle-container {
    display: none;
  }
}

.open {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdrop"></div>

<div class="toggle-container">
  <div class="bar1">
  </div>
  <div class="bar2">
  </div>
  <div class="bar3">
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="mobile-nav">
  <ul class="mobile-nav__items">
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile-nav__item">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Sorry about the formatting issues with the css

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I wanted to remove the backdrop, how could I only close the menu by clicking on the toggle after it's opened?

Comment: You would need to check if the menu is open, and if so, then remove all the open/active classes. Perhaps have a variable to keep the state of open/close, and use that to either add or remove the classes.